# Powershell script to copy files to remote server

Tags: powershell

I'd like to have files on a local machine and copy them to a remote machine on the internet.  For this reason, I can't use UNC files shares.  I'd also like to avoid using MSDeploy or FTP if possible.  Does powershell have an easy way to copy a bunch of files to a remote server?

Comment: What kind of server? What protocols does it support/can you access? e.g. HTTP with WebDAV, Windows CIFS, NFS, SSH/shell, FTP/SFTP, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at `BitsTransfer` module, might help you - http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd819420.aspx

Comment: If you run the transfer as a job, you might upload more jobs at a time.

Comment: I was able to get one file upload working, however I can't overwrite the web.config of my site.

Answer (score 0):

When the remote server is a Linux or UNIX system, I use PSCP.EXE, the Windows SCP client created by the developer of Putty. I also use Puttygen to create a key pair that can be used instead of interactive password authentication.